# How can i migrate to null safety?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Can anyone explain how can i migrate to null safety.

what are the steps i need to follow?
and also i need to know :
what are the impacts to our code after migration?
should i go with manual migration or auto migration?

My dart SDK is : 2.19.6
Flutter : 3.7.11

As a first step i executed "dart pub outdated --mode=null-safety"

i got the output as : dev dependencies : all support null safety.

Screenshot is attached below :
[image: screenshot]

Comment: see [Migrating to null safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide)

Comment: The [migration tool](https://dart.dev/resources/dart-3-migration#null-safety-migration-tools) is no longer available, so you need to manually migrate the code.

Comment: You can get the migration tool by installing a legacy version of flutter.  My favorite tool for that is Puro.  I have a video on using Puro to install a legacy flutter and use it for a project temporarily at https://youtu.be/olqmK-opexA?si=vZnU0lFy1heg-5Jh